# ¿Como eliminar un registro con relacion Many to Many en TypeORM?

Tags: sql, sql-server, nestjs, typeorm

Tengo un proyecto en NestJS con TypeORM y tengo una relacion de muchos a muchos,
ManyToMany:
empleado -> manager

*Employee.entity.ts*

```
@ManyToMany(type => Employees, employee => employee.managers)
@JoinColumn({ name: 'employee_uuid'})
employees: Employees[];

@ManyToMany(type => Employees, employee => employee.employees, { eager: false, cascade: true, onDelete: 'CASCADE'})
@JoinTable({ name: 'employee_managers', joinColumn: { name: 'employee_uuid', referencedColumnName: 'uuid'}, inverseJoinColumn: { name: 'manager_uuid', referencedColumnName: 'uuid'}})
managers: Employees[]
```

Las relaciones me funcionan perfectamente tanto para guardar, actualizar y asignar managers,
Puedo eliminar un empleado de la siguiente manera:

```
 await this._employeesRepository.delete(uuid);
```

Tenga asignado manager o no tenga, se elimina sin problema alguno.

El detalle viene cuando trato de eliminar un *manager* que tiene asignados **empleados**
me marca el siguiente error:

> Error: The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint
> "FK_61c4b4797c61414900a1646f04b". The conflict occurred in database
> "intranet_development", table "dbo.employee_managers", column
> 'manager_uuid'

Claro esta que no puedo eliminar ese manager porque se encuentra referenciado a otros empleados, pero como podria eliminarlo?

Saludos

Comment: y no deberias asignarle un nuevo manager a esos empleados? digo, por integridad referencial...

Comment: Es lo que estoy tratando de hacer, se me ocurre hacer un recorrido de los empleados asignados y asignar un nuevo manager, pero la duda es una vez reemplazado ¿podria eliminar?

Comment: lo probaste? supongo que depende de donde hayas marcado la integridad...